# multiple attributes in select2 field type

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm trying to set more than one attribute in a select2 type field.
For Example, I would like to show first_name and last_name as the label of my select values:

```
        $this->crud->addField([  // Select
        'label' => 'Employer',
        'type' => 'select2',
        'name' => 'employer_id', // the db column for the foreign key
        'entity' => 'employer', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
        'attribute' => 'first_name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
        'model' => 'App\Models\Employer' // foreign key model
    ], 'update/create/both');
```

Is there any suggestion?
Thanks.

Comment: I reply to myself. It can be done natively in laravel, with Accessors and Mutators (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators)

Comment: that does not work

Answer (score 1):

You can with a getter:

```
public function getIdentNameAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->ident} {$this->name}";
}
```

Then in your controller use:

```
"attribute" => "IdentName", // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
```

Answer (score 1):

In laravel, we can use **Accessor** for this purpose. [Ref. Link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

1, Create a method [a.k.a. accessor] in the ***parent Model*** (in your case 'App\Models\Employer')

```
public function getFullNameAttribute() {
   return $this->first_name.' '.$this->last_name;
}
```

2, Use it in your CrudController or anywhere in your app

```
'attribute' => 'full_name'
```